# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped) on malloc for a struct

Tags: c

I have an error of Segmentation Fault caused by line

```
*head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)+1);'
```

I'm pretty sure that I used the construct node and the malloc in the same way in others cases where all worked fine.
The program print here1 and then a Core Dump happen.

this is my code:

```
struct node {
    //int val ;
    struct node * next;
    unsigned char string[];
 } ;

void init_list(struct node ** head) {
    
    printf("here1 \n");
    fflush(stdout);
    *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node)+1);
    printf("here2\n"); 
    fflush(stdout); 
    if(!(*head)){
    
            printf("error malloc \n");
            fflush(stdout);
            return ;
    }
    //(*head) -> val = -1; 
    (*head) -> next = NULL;
    ((*head) -> string)[0]= '\0'; 
    return ;

  }

  int main(void) {
     struct node ** head;
     init_list(head) ;
     printf("hereee\n");
     fflush(stdout) ;
     fini_list(head);
     return 1;
  }
```

This is what Valgrind returns me:

```
==6688== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6688== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6688== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6688== Command: ./ex3
==6688== 
 heree 
==6688== Invalid write of size 8
==6688==    at 0x109267: init_list (ex3.c:43)
==6688==    by 0x1092E9: main (ex3.c:66)
==6688==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==6688== 
==6688== 
==6688== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==6688==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==6688==    at 0x109267: init_list (ex3.c:43)
==6688==    by 0x1092E9: main (ex3.c:66)
==6688==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==6688==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==6688==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the  
==6688==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==6688==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608  .
==6688== 
==6688== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6688==     in use at exit: 9 bytes in 1 blocks
==6688==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 1,033 bytes allocated
==6688== 
==6688== LEAK SUMMARY: 
==6688==    definitely lost: 9 bytes in 1 blocks
==6688==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6688==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6688==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6688==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6688== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==6688== 
==6688== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==6688== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What I can't really understand is that I have used the same construct other programs and it that cases all worked fine.

So , what happens in the previous case ??

Comment: In main,  `struct node ** head;` -> `struct node * head;` then `init_list(&head);`. And this would be the reason why the function takes a pointer to pointer in the first place.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. how can I fix the problem ?

Comment: @Lundin now it works but I can' explain why in other cases I used struct node ** head in the main an all works

Comment: It's because doing so invokes undefined behavior. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't see the rest of the program, only the offending line. In general when you have a heap corruption (not the case with your code) you either run the program under valgrind (look it up) or compile it with the address sanitizer flags (look it up), then see the first line where these tools report a problem.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but what is the `+1` supposed to do in your allocated memory size? A struct is not like a string where you need space for some terminating 0 byte.

Comment: @Gerhardh
 I used that because I initialized the head node of my list with a value of '\0' in the field string .

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that you have a flexible array member in your struct. Then it's clear for me.

Answer (score 5):

You pass an uninitialized pointer to your function:

```c
int main(void) {
     struct node ** head;
     init_list(head) ;
```

As a result, `head` does not contain a valid address and dereferencing it in `*head = ...` causes your crash. It is not related to `malloc`at all.

That is not the way how this function should be used. You cannot pass the new pointer to the caller this way.

Try this instead:

```c
int main(void) {
     struct node *head = NULL;
     init_list(&head) ;
```

Comment: Now it work , but in the past i used struct node** head in the main. Why your solution work in this case ?

Comment: The nasty thing abount undefined behaviour is that in case of an error it might even seem to work as expected.